# extract channels from bit wise encoded array

Tags: python, numpy, bitwise-and

I got an array with bitwise encoded 3 channels.
like this:

```
1 for channel 1
2 for channel 2
3 for channel 1 and 2
4 for channel 3
5 for channel 1 and 3
6 for channel 3 and 2
```

I know how to do it in Matlab `bitand(digital_word, 2^1)` with bitwise and, but if I try to do the same for python with eg. for channel 1 `np.bitwise_and(digital_word, 2^1)` I get gibberish out

I want to get out a one for a given channel if the channel is encoded by the bit.

Some examples:
input:

```
 array([0,0,1,0,1,0,3,4,5,6])
```

output:

```
channel 1: [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
channel 2: [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]
channel 3: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]
```

Comment: Can you show some example inputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you meant to achieve by using `2^1`, but using `np.bitwise_and` was the correct approach.

For example, you get the result for channel 1 with `np.bitwise_and(digital_word, 1)`:

```
>>> digital_word = np.array([0,0,1,0,1,0,3,4,5,6])
>>> np.bitwise_and(digital_word, 1)
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

For the higher-valued bits the result is almost what you want, but you need to right-shift it to get 1 instead of 2<sup>*n*</sup>.

```
>>> np.bitwise_and(digital_word, 2)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2])
>>> np.bitwise_and(digital_word, 2) >> 1
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

Note that to get the third bit, you need to bitwise-and with 4 (= 2<sup>**3**–1</sup>), not 3:

```
>>> np.bitwise_and(digital_word, 4)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4])
>>> np.bitwise_and(digital_word, 4) >> 2
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

In general, to get the `n`th bit:

```
np.bitwise_and(digital_word, (1 << n)) >> n
```

NumPy arrays also support the `&` bitwise operator, so this is equivalent:

```
(digital_word & (1 << n)) >> n
```

Comment: thanks that was the issue I did not bit switch in the end, the 2^X was a bit confusing but was intended to archive the same thing as you proposed :)